# How to get Row Index by cell value of Datatable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable and i have around 100 rows. i want to have a select query for datatable for  one value in Cell to get all the rows where the value of the cell matches.

Comment: use Linq, see this http://asadyousufi.blogspot.in/2009/11/complete-c-example-linq-datatable-query.html and google for more such links

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using DataTable.Select as explained in [DataTable.Select Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx)

To find a value in DataTable, use DataTable's Select() method:

```
DataRow[] rows = dt.Select("MyColumn = 123");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = (from x in dataTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                         where x.Field<string>("columnName") == "someValue"
                         select x).ToList();
```

Comment: Field is not resolved. i am getting this error. what does this x.Field for

Comment: You may need to add below line to your class.

using System.Data.DataRowExtensions;